# When there are two methods with the same name in the class and same parameter, the compiler looks at one over another?

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and this might sound very basic. The compiler always looks at the method that returns a const pixel value for me, which I do not want it to bc I want to change the value of the returned pixel. This situation does not happen during my previous assignments but it happens this time. Is there any way to resolve this? Thank you so much.

provided PNG class:

```
const HSLAPixel & getPixel(unsigned int x, unsigned int y) const;
HSLAPixel & getPixel(unsigned int x, unsigned int y);
```

my code:

```
HSLAPixel & original = png_.getPixel((*it).x, (*it).y);
```

Comment: How is `png_` declared?  Is it a *const* value or reference?  If so, then only the method with the `const;` suffix *can* be called (since you're not allowed to call a non-const method on a const-tagged object or reference), so that is the one the compiler will choose.

Comment: Hey Jeremy, thanks for helping out! png_ is a const value, I completely forgot about this!!

Comment: Those two do not have the same parameter list. The first one is marked `const`, so it can only be called on a `const` object; the second one can be called on a non-`const` object.

Answer (score 1):

They aren't quite the same. One is declared const. The other one is non-const. The compiler will use the const version when your PNG is marked const and the non-const version otherwise.

I did this:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
    void foo(int i) const { std::cout << "Const version.\n"; }
    void foo(int i) { std::cout << "Non-const version.\n"; }

    void myFunction() const { foo(10); }
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;

    foo.foo(10);
    foo.myFunction();
}
```

When I run it, the first call to `foo()` prints the Non-const message, and the second one prints the const message.